# Terminology for $[0,\infty)^n$

Tags: terminology

It dawned on me a couple of weeks ago that I had no idea what terminology was used for the sets $[0,\infty)^n\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ in general. In one dimension, it's just the half line; in two dimensions, it's a quadrant; in three dimensions, it's an octant. After that I am at a loss. Is there a name for these sets in general?

Comment: I think people tend to call it an "octant".

Comment: Well that's unsettling haha.

Comment: The positive/non-negative _orthant_.

Comment: Sorry - let's hope I'm wrong...

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Hah that's it! You should make that an answer.

Comment: Mimicing the manifold terminology, maybe let's call it a... corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often called the positive (if open) or non-negative (if closed) [*orthant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant).

Comment: Thanks! It has been bothering me for a couple of weeks. It is surprising that this terminology doesn't come up in basic courses and (seemingly) isn't that popular.

Comment: You're very welcome! It does seem like the sort of term one hears relatively rarely, and then only in scattered fields, such as toric geometry.